# numpy: comparing two date values returns TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a newby in python and numpy. While practicing I wrote this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': days, 'col2': data})
df = df.set_index('test')
print(df)
dates = np.array(df.index)
print(dates)
start_idx = np.where(dates>=datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d"))[0][-1]
print(start_idx)
```

but it give the below error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mohammadi/Desktop/sampleDF.py", line 15, in <module>
    start_idx = np.where(dates>=datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d"))[0][-1]
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: Which `numpy` version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the wrong objects. As numpy converts datetime objects into its own format, something like this `2018-09-25T11:48:44.959386000'`, Learn more about that [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

To make them compatible, Before you compare your dates convert your date into `numpy.datetime64` format and then compare. That should solve the problem.

So change your `start_idx` line to this  i.e line 15
`start_idx = np.where(dates>=np.datetime64(datetime.strptime('2018-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")))[0][-1]`

or you could directly convert the date like this
`np.datetime64('2018-01-01')`

Comment: You can just write `np.datetime64('2018-01-01')`. Also keep in mind that according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) the `datetime64` type is available starting from `numpy 1.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare directly without conversion.

```
start_idx = np.where(df.index>=datetime.strptime('2018-09-27', "%Y-%m-%d"))[0][-1]
```